# Any better solution about asynchronous query form main table and sub table?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, node-mysql

I have two tables, tb_article and tb_attach_url, like this

```
==============tb_article=================
id      title       content
1       "echo"      "test"
2       "foo"       "bar"
```

==============tb_attach_url==============

```
id      article_id      url_val
1       2               "http://.../foo.png"
2       2               "http://.../bar.png"
3       1               "http://.../test.png"
```

My scenario is like this, 
I want show a list of tb_article,
but tb_attach_url's information need also.

My solution is like this:

```
function load_article_urls(id, idx, callback){
    connection.query("select url_str from tb_attach_url where article_id = ?", [id], function(err, results){
        if (err) throw err;

        var images = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++){
            images.push(results[j]["url_str"]);
        }
        callback(idx, images)
    });
}

function load_article(req, res){
    connection.query('select * from tb_article where id = ?', [req.query.id], function(err, results){
        if (err) throw err;

        var cnt = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

            load_article_urls(results[i].id, i, function(idx, urls){

                results[idx]["urlset"] = urls;

                cnt++;
                if (cnt == results.length){
                    //waiting for all back
                    res.render('list_article', { article_list: results});
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I think this implement is little ugly, and want to know some better ways. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async.map` ([GitHub](https://github.com/caolan/async#map)) to do something like this:

```
async.map(results,
  function (err, callback) { /* Call callback with the urls as a parameter here */ },
  function (err, allUrls) {
    // Combine results and allUrls - they are in the same order.
})
```

Or use some of the other functionalities of `async` to achieve a similar effect.